# How can I set up some personal snippets for shebang lines or python exception handlers?

Tags: snippets

I want to to add some functions to my vimrc and want to achieve, *e.g.*,

- I type `:bang` and it adds a shebang into the file
- I type `class foo:<ENTER>` it automatically adds `except KeyboardInterrupt:` 2-3 lines after.

Comment: The given answer is good. If you want something more powerful, though, you should look at using a snippet plugin like Ultisnips. You'll find snippets for all major programming languages and you can easily add your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to learn about insert mode abbreviations.

```
:iabbrev :bang #!/usr/bin/python3.9
```

When you type `:bang` in INSERT mode, the text will be replaced to `#!/usr/bin/python3.9` when you trigger the abbreviation.   Abbreviations are triggered when you hit the space bar or return key (among other ways).

For an abbreviation with multi-lines, use the `<cr>` for carriage return.

```
:iabbrev foo: foo:<cr><cr>    except keyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: looks nice but it does not work: got always on error loading my vimrc Tried with :iabbrev or set iabbrev and just iabbrev 
Vim version 8.1.2269

Comment: @user37716 what error?

Comment: well, "command not found", but got it right now and wanted to reply. :)
I had to add it like:
:ab try try:<cr>except keyboardInterrupt:
in my vimrc

but now I have an indent after that <cr>
Do vim now mixing up with python syntax?

Comment: I don't understand why :iabbrev wouldn't work.  That's a valid command.  You probably spelled it wrong.

The indent appeared because your filetype is set to python and you have auto-indentation for python.   Return after a colon will indent.

Comment: omg. i cant be that fool. you were right. just tested it again. so, goal achieved and brought another easter egg. do you think there is a workaround for this indent - as i dont want it to turn off. i've read about special characters, maybe to put a backspace after <cr>?

Comment: yes, you could try <bs> after <cr>